# Positive integers as sum or difference of consecutive square numbers

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, number-theory

Is it possible to represent each positive integer n in the form
$n=\pm1^2\pm2^2\pm3^2...\pm m^2$ ?
Examples:
$1=+1^2$
$2=-1^2-2^2-3^2+4^2$
$3=-1^2+2^2$
$4=-1^2-2^2+3^2$

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is

> possible.

Reason:

> $$k^2-(k+1)^2-(k+2)^2+(k+3)^2 = 4$$
>  So starting from the given solutions for $1$ to $4$, you can add the next four square terms using the signs $+--+$ to get solutions for $5$ to $8$. For example:
>  $5=+1^2+2^2-3^2-4^2+5^2$
>  $6=-1^2-2^2-3^2+4^2+5^2-6^2-7^2+8^2$
>  Obviously this is not optimal. You can repeat this to get solutions for the next four integers $9$ to $12$, and again for $13$ to $16$, and so on up to any positive integer.

Comment: Whoa. This is really cool!!!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, one can.

Now simply pick two consecutive numbers a,b,(a<b).

Now use (a^2-b^2). Expanding it you end up with (a+b)(a-b).[(a-b)=1]

Now it ends up with (2a+1)-----(1)
For all whole number values of a.
If you pick next two consecutive integers the difference would be 2(a+2)+1-------(2).
So upon subtracting 1 from 2.You would get a 4.
It means you can pick four consecutive numbers starting from any integer a and get a result of 4.

Since you have already made the expressions for first 4 numbers, you can just add them to the sequence starting with next four digits to get the entire expression.

Comment: The number is supposed to be written using ALL the squares starting from $1^2$ up to some number $m^2$. Just writing for example $7=4^2-3^2$ does not count since it does not use $1^2$ and $2^2$.

Comment: @PiGuy one you establish a result of 4 with four consecutive integers, and already the op has given expressions for 1,2,3,4.So you simply add the next 4 consecutive integers mix to the already established espression. For example,every 4n+3 can be written using the expression of 3 and then adding 4 consecutive integers for every addition of 4. In total it require m-1 integers for this case.I think you got my meaning.Right before the editing of this answer i meant the same but jaap made a comment on not including every integer.

Comment: Could you explain further on what you are meaning? Is it intended to be similar to the answer by @JaapScherphuis? Your wording is not very clear.

Comment: @PiGuy, Yes similar to that of jaap's answer.I am providin an explanation of how did we arrive at four at the first instant and that is the whole part of the story,right.

Comment: I see now. Thank you for elaborating. : )